# Smallest integer value greater than or equal to value of log

Tags: python, int, logarithm

I have some integer count suppose '51' and I want represent that much of integers in binary number. Here I need to do `log(51)` so i get some float value as `3.93182563272`. But I want it in some integer format as `4` which could be used to represent 51 integers.
Log value can be calculated as

```
import math
math.log(51)
```

Comment: You mean you want to round up the float to the nearest integer?

Comment: Logarithm in which base? Since you mention binary numbers, I suspect base 2 log. In that case, be aware that `math.log` doesn't do that, it uses base e (natural logarithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the number of binary digits, that would be base `2`, whereas [`math.log`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.log) by default returns the *natural logarithm* (base `e`). A second argument can be used to specify an alternative base. Then you can use [`math.ceil`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.ceil) to round up the number.

```
math.ceil(math.log(51, 2))
6.0
```

You haven't specified a python version but if you have python 3, (thanks @delnan), you can use [`math.log2`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log2) instead, which should be more accurate:

```
math.ceil(math.log2(51))
6.0
```

[`numpy` also has a log2 method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.log2.html) (but is probably overkill for this application).

`math.ceil` actually returns a float, so if you want an integer you can wrap the expression in `int`:

```
int(math.ceil(math.log(51, 2)))
6
```

By the way, there is also the function [`bin`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin) which you might want to look at. It returns a string containing the binary representation of an integer:

```
bin(51)
'0b110011'
```

---

...but if you don't want to mess around with any of that (thanks again @delnan), you can just use [`bit_length`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_length) instead:

```
(51).bit_length()    
6
```

Comment: FYI `math.log(x, 2)` is less accurate than `math.log2(x)`, and `int(ceil(log2(x))` is in many ways worse than `x.bit_length()` if `x` is an integer.

Comment: @delnan I don't have math.log2 (python 2.7.3). I notice that numpy has a log2 method, is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I assumed Python 3's `math` and `int`. I rarely work with 2.x these days so I sometimes forget what's backported and what's not.

Comment: @delnan thanks for your contributions, I've edited so that hopefully all of it has been included.

Comment: @TomFenech thank you. I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ceiling "round up" function before you cast it to an int:

```
math.ceil(math.log(51)) # round up
```

You should also have a look at:

```
math.floor() # round down
math.round()
```

If you need to save it as a integer type you can cast it to that type:

```
int()
```

Comment: Note that `math.log` by default gives the natural logarithm, which is probably not what the OP wants.